# Set Value of Array-Element within another Array

Tags: c#, mongodb

Document-Structure looks like this:

```
_id
Name
Stations: Array
    0: Object
      ID
      Name
      Processes: Array
          0: Object
              ID
              Name
```

I want to change the Name of a Process. Type, Station and Process is selected via ComboBoxes.

I tryed something like this:

```
 var filter = Builders<TEAM_Type>.Filter.Eq("Stations.Processes.TID", (CB_SelectStation.SelectedItem as StationDescription).Processes[selectedItemStorage].TID);

 var update = Builders<TEAM_Type>.Update.Set("Stations.$.Processes.$.Name", ((sender as ComboBox).Text));

 db.GetCollection<TEAM_Type>("types").UpdateMany(filter, update);
```

But i get the exception

```
  Too many positional (i.e. '$') elements found in path 'Stations.$.Processes.$.Name'"
```

I also tryed

```
var filter = Builders<TEAM_Type>.Filter.And(
                Builders<TEAM_Type>.Filter.Eq("Stations.TID", (CB_SelectStation.SelectedItem as StationDescription).TID),
                Builders<TEAM_Type>.Filter.Eq("Stations.Processes.TID", (CB_SelectStation.SelectedItem as StationDescription).Processes[selectedItemStorage].TID)
                );

var update = Builders<TEAM_Type>.Update.Set("Stations.Processes.$.Name", ((sender as ComboBox).Text));

db.GetCollection<TEAM_Type>("types").UpdateMany(filter, update);
```

But got this

```
Cannot create field 'Processes' in element {Stations: [ { TID: 1, Name: "Station 1", IPAddress: null, Processes: [ { TID: 2, Name: "Process 2", Limits: [], Constants: [] } ] } ]}"
```

How can i set the name of an Element of an array within another array?
Preferably even within another array...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it right...

```
var filter = Builders<TEAM_Type>.Filter.And(
                Builders<TEAM_Type>.Filter.Eq("Stations.TID", (CB_SelectStation.SelectedItem as StationDescription).TID),
                Builders<TEAM_Type>.Filter.Eq("Stations.Processes.TID", (CB_SelectStation.SelectedItem as StationDescription).Processes[selectedItemStorage].TID)
                );

var update = Builders<TEAM_Type>.Update.Set("Stations.$[].Processes.$.Name", ((sender as ComboBox).Text));

db.GetCollection<TEAM_Type>("types").UpdateMany(filter, update);
```

using $[] instead if $ for the stations tells the set-command to update all found indexes of stations. so it seams anyway.